# How to pass credentials into an API request preceding the server IP in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I know that using variables you can pass in the username and password to a API call but that appends to the request under test:

Instead of eg. `https://api-server.com/test/somekey${USERNAME}${PWD}`

I would like to send:

`https://${USERNAME}:${PWD}@api-server.com/test/somekey`

When I try this it throws an error `null` if I place the colon between the username and password variables; so is there a way to pass the ':' into the HTTP request or an alternative solution?

Note: The purpose of the test is to feed in via CSV config a CSV with multiple username, passwords to check access permissions etc. I currently use a single HTTP Authorization Manager to test a number of API calls for a single user. Alternatively, however, I wish to run some API tests in the suite for a number of other users, so how could I achiever this?

Comment: You are missing the ${PWD} in your example.   I tried a quick example with https://${user}:${pass}$@myhost.com/  and User Defined Variables and it worked.  You can also use [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager),  I can post an example if your interested.

Comment: I missed it when typing it above and corrected it but everything works fine until I insert the colon sign ':' in between the variables. I updated the description as I'm using a CSV config to test multiple credentials for a HTTP request so I don't think the authorization manager may suit this.

Comment: @RichardFriedman If this has worked for you, could you please post an example illustrating how https://${user}:${pass}$@myhost.com/ this has worked, so I could see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the only way I could make this fail was by using Java as the HTTP Implementation, selecting HTTPClient4 it works just fine.

I have two examples with JMX Files. Both tests prove the same results. The CSV contains 9 valid auth creds and one invalid, just to make sure both cases work.

Example 1. Link to JMX Test and File - [HTTP Auth Manager with CSV](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11663).

- HTTP Authorization Manager
- CSV Data Set Config
- HTTP Request (without full url)

This works fine, the only trick is you can use ${user} and ${pass} from your csv within HTTP Authorization Manager.

Example 2. Link to JMX Test and File - [HTTP Request with URL](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11664)

- HTTP Request with full url
- Using HTTPClient4
- CSV Data Set Config

This is specific to the case you describe, I just specify HTTPClient4
The test cases I tested running on 5 servers, each with 60 users/threads, looping 5 times.  So generated about 3000 requests.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution, much appreciated. Another thing to add would be checking the 'Clear auth on each iteration' or else the session is cached.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) (make sure that you select BASIC_DIGEST mechanism) as a child of the request you want to pass credentials with - in that case it will affect only one request.

If you need to supply authorization on multiple requests - put HTTP Authorization Manager so requests would be on the same level or children of the HTTP Authorization Manager.

See [How to use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this approach but I need to supply different authorization/credentials for the same REST API request within the same Thread Group.

Answer (score 0):

```js
user_name = "user"
user_password = "somepasword"
data = '{\"username\":\"'+user_name+'\",\"password\":\"'+user_password+'\"}'
print(data)
```

Where **user_name** and **user_password** are the variables possessing the username and password respectively.

Below is the complete URL
**response = requests.post('https://xxx/api/v1/auth/token', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)**